# span inside div and different font size alignment

Tags: css

I have 3 spans inside a div.

```
<div class="align">
  <span class="a">Title</span>
  <span class="b">Someinfomation</span>
  <span class="c">Toright</span>
</div>
```

for making the `c` class to align vertically, I have to use margin-top to fix it
however, for IE7 looks differently.
Here is online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wZmGQ/

Yes, I want IE7 works as well.
If someone could help me with a better solution?Thanks

Solution is shown below, for someone who looks for IE7 solution

Got the answer from [float: right in IE7 dropping to a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797573/float-right-in-ie7-dropping-to-a-new-line)

> Try to small change markup: place items with a float before items
>   without it (from the same row). It should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you `float` an element, you are *implicitly* declaring `display:block`.  So when you write the following code:

```
.some-element {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

... is the same exact thing as doing this:

```
.some-element {
    display: inline-block;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

... but I realize that doesn't help you much.  Check out this fiddle, sorry I can't test in IE7 at the moment, but see if this helps get you in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/wZmGQ/3/

Essentially this:

```
.align{
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 35px; /* larger than your largest font size */
}
.a, .b, .c {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it's much better than margin-top, I think for IE7, I'd better to hack by a separate css rule

Answer (score 0):

Create an ie only stylesheet. http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/